# Black Screen of death?

Tags: firefox, screen, chromium

Hello there I have a problem regarding Black Screen on mine Ubuntu 14.04. 
Short version. When I play a video on Chromiun Web Browser I got an instant nasty black screen. This especially happens when I am playing youtube videos, music and stuff.
On the other hand Firefox is another story, this does not happening at all, but when I run multiple browsers I have an instant black screen.
Mine question is, can you tell me where to look, and how to over some this.
Tank you.

Comment: Please tell us more about your system, such as display chipset and the amount of RAM in your system.

Comment: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T8300 @ 2.40GHz × 2, Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2,2 GiB, 32-bit sistem, @gyropyge

Comment: I would advise you not to run multiple concurrent browsers.

Comment: OK, tank you for the advise, @gyropyge